# JAVA: ¿Como Utilizar varios for o forEach al mismo tiempo?

Tags: java

tengo otro problema haber si me pueden aclarar, esto:

Tengo un forEach y un for los cuales me acarrean valores para una tabla al mismo tiempo, el detalle esta que quiero ingresar otros valores múltiples pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo ya que al meter otro for o forEach lo que hace es duplicar los valores.

Esta es la forma con que acarreo a un jtable información y la lleno usando un for y un forEach

```
fechasRecibo.forEach(c -> {
            //System.out.println("Fecha: " + c);//De aqui extraigo un valor de fechas de arrays
            String datos[] = new String[3];
            for (int i = 0; i < miTabla.getRowCount(); i++) {
            datos[0] = (String)miTabla.getValueAt(i, 0);//Este
            datos[1] = (String)miTabla.getValueAt(i, 1);//y Este valor se extrae de otra tabla
            datos[2] = c;//valor que se extrae de un array
            //datos[3] = txtNombreDelGrupoRegistrar.getText();//este es el id y no importa que se repita
            modelo2.addRow(datos);//Mando la info a la otra tabla
            }});
```

El detalle esta que no encuentro forma para ingresar otro sin que me duplique el contenido

Intente algo así pero me duplica la información:

```
fechasRecibo.forEach(c -> {
            folios.forEach(d -> {
            //System.out.println("Fecha: " + c);
            String datos[] = new String[4];
            for (int i = 0; i < miTabla.getRowCount(); i++) {
            datos[0] = (String)miTabla.getValueAt(i, 0);
            datos[1] = (String)miTabla.getValueAt(i, 1);
            datos[2] = c;
            datos[3] = d;
            //datos[3] = txtNombreDelGrupoRegistrar.getText();
            modelo2.addRow(datos);
            }});});
```

Comment: Creo que no es al mismo tiempo, si estuviera usando hilos, en ese caso si seria al mismo tiempo. Lo que te pasa es que necesitas una columna de tipo "pivote", una columna con un id único, dentro del ciclo pones una condición que verifique que el valor que se va a ingresar  no se repita y listo.

Comment: No, de echo ya el foreach lo deje de usar porque el arraylist entre mas datos tiene mas lento se vuelve el ingreso de nuevos datos a la hora de generar numeros consecutivos del 1 al 7405 empieza 1,2,3..4...5....6......7.......8...........9 hasta llegar a un punto que le lleva horas generar otro numero consecutivo.

Comment: El problema ahora es que al parecer no encuentro la forma de explicar lo que quiero lograr, creí haberlo resuelto, colocando mis datos directamente a la tabla pero lamentablemente los datos que tomo de la primer tabla hereda la cantidad de registros que contiene y a la hora que quiero generar números consecutivos como mi otra tabla tiene 7404 registros cuando quiero agregar a partir de 7405 en adelante me dice que el index esta fuera y no puedo generar esos numeros, si es del 1 al 7404 lo realiza perfectamente empieza 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 pero si quiero empezar de 7405 no me deja.

Comment: ahorita ando buscando una manera que ya que ingrese ciertos datos y ocupan 5 columnas entonces generar los números consecutivos que deseo y añadir en esa información existente una sexta columna pero no encuentro como hacerlo.